# Don't resolve to macrovariable text returned by %substr() with & at the begining

Tags: sas-macro

I'm trying to quote a substring of a macro variable. The code is:

```
%let hola=resuelto!;

%macro prueba(param);
    %let amper=&param;
    %let amper2=%nrbquote(%substr(&param,1,3));
    %put &param;
    %put &amper;
    %put &amper2;
%mend;

%prueba(%nrstr(&hola));
```

In the log, I'm getting:

```
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference HO not resolved.
&hola
&hola
&ho
```

The problem is I need to assign `amper2` literally the value `&ho`, without any attempt of resolution, like I do with `amper`, that gets literally the string `&hola`... any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing

```
%nrbquote(%substr(&param,1,3))
```

to

```
%qsubstr(&param,1,3)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: @Alex Could you please mark it as answear you were looking for?